# LSD on BMW M3 or 330ci E46

Tags: bmw, lsd

There is an LSD for BWM. Can anyone give me an link to sale of this where I can find LSD for BWM M3 E46 / E36, or BWM E46 330i?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'M's should come with an LSD from the factory, so you should be able to find a used one from a specialist BMW parts supplier. I'd also think that the usual manufacturers of LSD have one that would fit, but they're most likely not cheap.

Answer (score 0):

It should be noted that there are parts in an LSD which eventually wear out. Therefore an old LSD might require a rebuild to restore the function of limiting slip.